# TextBlock fit text in ListView

Tags: c#, uwp, textblock

How do I set the length of the `TextBlock` so it fits in a `ListViewItem`?
This is my xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="flyList" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FF7C7C7C">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped" SelectionHighlightColor="#FF8F8F8F">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Name="tip1" Content="Click to copy signal to clipboard."/>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If the text is longer that the `ListViewItem` width, the rest of the text is not visible obviously. Is there an easy way to make fit in it other than hardcode the text?

Comment: Can you show screen captures?

Comment: Try adding `TextWrapping="Wrap"` to the TextBlock

Comment: TextWrapping doesnt work exactly the same way on UWP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@CETINKAYA Ayta Ozden have a good way to solution but I think I should give you a code to explain.

The first thing is set ItemContainerStyle that use the code:

```
      <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                            Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And replace the StackPanel to Grid.

And add `TextWrapping="Wrap"` to TextBlock. @WPInfo Thx your way.

If you set the StackPanel that will make the min width and if you have not set the ItemContainerStyle that it's default is Left that means it will use the min width.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use a stackpanel for parent element ? And add HorizontalAlignment to Textblock.
Else define the itemcontainer style With HorizontalContentAlignment to Stretch you can easyly find some examples.

Comment: It's UWP not WPF